# Priority of execution of runs in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Suppose there are two run function in app:

```html
angular.module('exmple',[])
.run(function(){
    console.log('second');
})
.run(function(){
    console.log('first');
});
```

Is there any way to execute runs based on priority?

Comment: what priority ?

Comment: A run block executed first if its priority is the biggest.

Comment: but what do you mean with priority of a run block? you can define priority on components/directives, but a run is executed simply when is found. Why you don't just structure your code in order to execute the one you want before the other one?

Comment: One of the run block are responsible to load configuration from server and  init some basic services. Others are from modules and plugins. The first must be executed before the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If code is in a service, it will run in order of dependency:

```
angular.module('exmple',[])
.run(function(firstService){
    console.log('second');
})
.service("firstService", function(){
    console.log('first');
});
```

By having the run block define `firstService` as a dependency, the dependency injector will initialize that service before running the code of the run block.

## The Demo

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.run(function(firstService){
    console.log('second');
})
.service("firstService", function(){
    console.log('first');
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
</div>
```